# Messy code when dealing with several bleak-clients at once

Tags: python, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently making a project where I'm trying to create an expandable program for n devices connected over BLE using bleak. The controllers shall be connected to the main hub (Raspberry pi) simultaneously. In my attempt to do so, my only solution so far is using nested 'with'-statements. This just winds up being messy, as well as not being self-expanding when dealing with more devices.

My code thus far;

```
import asyncio
import bleak
from bleak import BleakClient

# [Callback-functions and more]

async def main(addresses):
    try:
        async with BleakClient(addresses[0]) as client0:
            await client0.start_notify(UUID, callback0)
            print(f"Connected: {client0.is_connected}")
            controllers.append(client0)
            async with BleakClient(addresses[1]) as client1:
                await client1.start_notify(UUID, callback1)
                print(f"Connected: {client1.is_connected}")
                controllers.append(client1)
                async with BleakClient(addresses[2]) as client2:
                    await client2.start_notify(UUID, callback2)
                    print(f"Connected: {client2.is_connected}")
                    controllers.append(client2)
                    async with BleakClient(addresses[3]) as client3:
                        print(f"Connected: {client3.is_connected}")
                        controllers.append(client3)
                        await client3.start_notify(UUID, callback3)

                        # [Rest of code]

                        await client0.stop_notify(UUID)
                        await client1.stop_notify(UUID)
                        await client2.stop_notify(UUID)
                        await client3.stop_notify(UUID)
     except bleak.exc.BleakDBusError:
         await main(addresses)
```

If you have any idea on how to do this with for example some kind of for-loop, that'd be great.

Comment: Does the following example in the GitHub repo help? https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/two_devices.py Or do it without the context manager as shown at https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#usage  The other thing to note is that while the Bluetooth spec does not have a limit on the number of connections, the really of putting resources into chips means that only a handful of concurrent connections are supported by most BLE chips.

Comment: I've read the example. The only problem is the fact that the connections as closed at once as it exits the with-statement. I found another way though. I thank you for your attempt!